# Adding On Load Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to have my javascript code load without me having to refresh the page.

This is the current code I am having. How would I add an onload function into this?

```
lastUrl = document.referrer;

   if(lastUrl.search("website") == -1) {
      $( ".anumber" ).each(function() {
         $(this).html("03 9416 9233");
   });
}
```

UPDATED CODE -----

This code is now reloading the page and executing the number change correctly. I now need help with getting this to action ONCE only and stop. At the moment the page just keeps reloading and reloading.

```
window.addEventListener('load', initReload, false);
function initReload() {
    window.location.reload();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    lastUrl = document.referrer;
      if(lastUrl.indexOf("website") == -1) {
        $( ".anumber" ).each(function() { 
           $(this).html("0438 000 111");
      });
    }
 });
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: I am looking for the web page to refresh ONCE before when the code runs. Please look at updated code above. I have the page reloading just need to get it to load once only. This code is now reloading the page over and over.

Comment: Use ajax for this if you want only some part of your code to load without refresh

Comment: I don't know ajax syntax for this to work. Please show example.

Comment: which language you use for backend?

Comment: HTML, CSS and JQuery/Javascript

Comment: Can you create your working code in fiddle or anything? SO I can access it and understand what do you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could fit for you?

```
$(window).one( "load", function() {
 initReload();
});
```

Comment: after the jquery inclusion